# Why does testing fetch call fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, fetch-api

I am trying to duplicate the react fetch test code in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FIrK8fSp80 (At 11:51 in the video, enough relevant code should be visible to see what is going on). I thought I had my code very close to what is in the video, but I am not getting the same result. Yes, I am resolving a string, not a number like in the video.

When the app is run, it works fine and displays "Name: bill" on the screen.

When I run the test that expects "Name: bill" to be in the document, it fails with the below error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Unable to find an element with the text: Name: bill. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="App"
    >
      <header
        class="App-header"
      >
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>
              Name: 
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

  12 |   } as any)
  13 |   render(<App />);
> 14 |   await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("Name: bill")).toBeInTheDocument);
     |                ^
  15 | });
  16 |

  at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:166:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:14:16)
```

App files:

```
    _______
    mydata.json: {"name":"bill","age":"50"}
    
    _______
    Api.tsx
    import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    
    export default function FileUploadPage(){
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch('mydata.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setName(res.name))
        .catch(console.error)  
      }, [])
      return(
        <div>
          <span>Name: {name}</span>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    _______
    AppContainer.tsx
    import React from 'react';
    import FileUploadPage from './Api.tsx';
    
    export default function MyContainer() {
      return(
          <div>
            <FileUploadPage />
          </div>
      );
    }
    
    _______
    App.js
    import React from "react";
    import './App.css';
    import MyContainer from "./components/AppContainer.tsx";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <MyContainer />        
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default App;
    
    _______
Test file
    import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
    import App from './App';
    import React from 'react';
    
    global.fetch = jest.fn();
    
    const mockFetch = fetch as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch>;
    
    it.only('fetch call', async () => {
      mockFetch.mockResolvedValue({
        json: () => Promise.resolve("bill")
      } as any)
      render(<App />);
      await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("Name: bill")).toBeInTheDocument);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your test code is that you are resolving the `json` function of the mock response with a string directly (`"bill"`) instead of an `object` with a `name` property. To fix this, you need to resolve it with an object that matches the structure of your JSON file.

```js
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';

global.fetch = jest.fn();

const mockFetch = fetch as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch>;

it('fetch call', async () => {
  mockFetch.mockResolvedValue({
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ name: "bill" }) // Resolve with an object containing the "name" property
  } as Response); // Cast the mock response to Response type

  render(<App />);
  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("Name: bill")).toBeInTheDocument);
});
```

I my example the `json` function of the mock response is resolved with an object `{ name: "bill" }`, which matches the structure of your JSON file.

You will also need to update the `useEffect` in your `FileUploadPage` to handle it.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function FileUploadPage() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('mydata.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setName(data.name);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Name: {name}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So by using `data` object you will access all their properties like `name` and then you can just set it by:

```
setName(data.name)
```

Comment: From what i can see, my useEffect looks exactly like yours, so not sure what needs updating.